# How can I automate the backing up of cron jobs?

Tags: 11.10, cron

In the even of a crash I realize that I may not be backing up system and user cron jobs.  How can I automate the backing up of my systems cron jobs?

Comment: `<snide remark>` With another cronjob of course! `</snide remark>` - in all seriousness though, good question. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yeah another cronjob for the automation but in terms of collecting everything together, there are a few directories you want to cater for:

```
/etc/cron.*
/var/spool/cron/crontabs/
```

Back those up, and you should have everything. You can do that with:

```
sudo tar cvf cron-backup.tar /etc/cron.* /var/spool/cron/crontabs
```

Answer (score 1):

crontab -l > /path/to/your/backup/file

For example:

crontab -l > /var/backups/${USER}.crontab.list